# Using Parallax Effect, 'Active' Nav Option Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The website is right here:

So if you click on contact, you can see that Features is still active instead of the Contact link only. I am not sure what's causing this to classify as active but I would appreciate any help you could give.

Thank you!

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your `slide5` and `slide6` div's are inside `div with id="slide4"`. Hence 4 is also active.

Meaning, currently it's

```
<div class="slide" id="slide4">
   <div class="slide" id="slide5">
         ....
    </div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide6">
        ....
      </div>
</div>
```

**Change it to:**

```
<div class="slide" id="slide4">
   ....
</div>
<div class="slide" id="slide5">
    ....
</div>
<div class="slide" id="slide6">
   ....
</div>
```